# how to declare variable in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers

this is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER proximo_pago 
AFTER INSERT ON pago FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_orden integer;
    DECLARE num_lote =NEW.lote;
        BEGIN
            SET max_orden = (SELECT MAX(orden) FROM PAGO WHERE LOTE=num_lote);
            SELECT max_orden INTO : NEW.orden from dual;
            END
END
```

and the error

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER proximo_pago 
AFTER INSERT ON pago FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE max_orden integer;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: did you change the delimeter? if not, then the `;` on your first declare is terminating the entire trigger definition.

Comment: You need to change the delimiter before defining the trigger. Try `delimiter /` and put that character also at the end of your trigger definition.

Answer (score 4):

```
 DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(10);
 DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5);
```

or if you want to assign you can use

```
 DECLARE TEMP INT DEFAULT 6;
```

To assign a variable

```
myvariable := TEMPKODE;
SET myvariable := TEMPKODE;
```

Maybe what you mean is :

```
CREATE TRIGGER proximo_pago 
AFTER INSERT ON pago FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE max_orden INT;
DECLARE num_lote INT;
    BEGIN
        SET num_lote := NEW.lote;
        SELECT MAX(ordern) INTO max_ordern FROM PAGO WHERE LOTE = num_lote;
        SET NEW.ordern := max_ordern;

END
```